# Quasiconcavity of a product of ratios

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $f(x_1\ldots x_k) = \dfrac{x_1x_2\cdots x_k}{(x_0+c_1)(x_0+c_2)\cdots(x_0+c_k)}$

where $x_i > 0$, the $c_i > 0$ are constants, and

$$x_0 = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i$$

is it true that $f$ is quasiconcave? I suspect that it is,
for the following reasons:

1. If $k = 2$, one can show directly using the bordered Hessian that
   $f$ is quasiconcave under the given conditions. Extending this to
   higher dimensions gets messy, though.
2. If all $c_i$ were set to the same value $c>0$, then $f$ is also
   quasiconcave. This is because $\log f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k \log
   \frac{x_i}{x_0+c}$ can be seen to be an affine-fractional composition
   with a quasiconcave function, which is thus quasiconcave. This in
   turn implies that $f$ is quasiconcave because exponentiating is
   composition with an increasing function, which preserves quasiconcavity. Unfortunately, my $c_i$ are different, so this does not directly help.

I am a mere practitioner of convex optimization and no expert, so
apologies for missing anything obvious.

Comment: I don't understand why #2 is holding you back. After all, can't you write your function as an affine-fractional composition with a quasiconcave function? If not, how do you manage it when the $c_i$ values are identical?

Comment: @MichaelGrant The property I was referring to (see e.g. Boyd and Vandenberghe Sec 3.3.4, and proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603735/243498) following my recent question) requires the denominator of the transformation in the composition to be the same for each component. I tried extending the proof linked above to the case where the constant portion of the denominators are different, as occurs in my present question, to no avail. This no longer meets the definition of "affine-fractional transformation" as far as I know.